# Android - write to file from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-file

I'm in the process of migrating activities to fragments, and I'm having issues with writing data to a .txt file, nothing happens when I click the "save data" button. When I say "nothing", I mean the toast notification doesn't occur and the file doesn't write.

Here's what I have so far:

Listener for the "save data" button:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.myDatePickerButton:
                 **unused for this**

            break;
        case R.id.saveGenInfoButton:
            writeToFile();

            break;
    }
}
```

writeToFile method

```
private void writeToFile() {


    String outputString = ("Output\n" + "\n" + fiView1.getText().toString() + outputFOI1.getText().toString()
            + "\n" + fiView2.getText().toString() + outputFOI2.getText().toString() + "\n" + districtView.getText().toString() + outputEngineeringDistrict.getText().toString() + "\n"
            + countyView.getText().toString() + outputCountyName.getText().toString() + "\n" + municipalityView.getText().toString() + outputMunicipalityName.getText().toString());

    String filename = (outputFileName.getText().toString() + ".txt");

    try {
        File outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), filename);

        outputFile.createNewFile();

        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(getActivity().openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        writer.write(outputString);
        writer.close();
        Toast
                .makeText(getActivity(), "Information saved to SD card as " + filename, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    } catch (Throwable t)

    {
        Toast
                .makeText(getActivity(), "Exception: " + t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
```

also, my variables are set up in onStart as such:

```
    outputDOI = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.outputDOI);
    doiView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.doiView);
    fiView1 = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.fiView1);
    outputFOI1 = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.outputFOI1);
    fiView2 = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.fiView2);
    outputFOI2 = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.outputFOI2);
    districtView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.districtView);
    outputEngineeringDistrict = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.outputEngineeringDistrict);
    countyView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.countyView);
    outputCountyName = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.outputCountyName);
    municipalityView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.municipalityView);
    outputMunicipalityName = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.outputMunicipalityName);
    outputFileName = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.outputFilename);
    save_gen_info_button = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.saveGenInfoButton);
```

Comment: Post the logcat here; I am suspecting you are not getting the data correctly; remember, in fragments, you get reference components by using the view that you return in onCreateView. Also, after calling getText() call toString() as well.

Comment: @Eenvincible, I was able to fix the crashing but now the file doesn't write. I updated the original post.

Comment: If you have your fragment, inside the onCreateView method, you should create a view by inflating the layout. Then, before turning that view, you can get the references to all your text views and edit texts. I am just making sure you are getting your references by saying view.findViewById() instead of getView() method - still that might not be causing the problem here. A log cat portion might help still.